# SQL Counting the value for each element

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables in db2 and I want to calculate the amount for each item.
In first table I have:

```
SELECT sum(AMOUNT_CUR) AS amount, ID_1
FROM TAB_SCHEMA.TAB1 
WHERE ID_1 = '0000710195|000100179390'
GROUP BY ID_1
```

[image]

and second table where I have:

```
SELECT 
DATE_1, AMOUNT_PLN1 
FROM TAB_SCHEMA.TAB2 
WHERE ID_1 = '0000710195|000100179390'
ORDER BY DATE_1 ASC
```

[image]

i would like to get something like this. For the first item from TAB2, calculate the difference, i.e.

```
DATE_1    amount_2
20191231  9613170,76-3902609,95 = 5710560,81 (amount-AMOUNT_PLN1)
20200229  5710560,81-557515,71 = 5153045,1 
20200331  5153045,1-2779121,54 ...
```

Anyone have an idea how to do it easily?
Maybe some function?

Answer (score 0):

You need OLAP Specifications, specifically `SUM() OVER()`

```
with
tab1 (amount, id_1) as (values (10, 1)),
tab2 (id_1, date_1, amount_pln1) as (
    values
    (1, date '2019-12-31', 1),
    (1, date '2020-02-29', 2),
    (1, date '2020-03-31', 3)
)
select
    tab2.date_1,
    tab1.amount - coalesce(sum(tab2.amount_pln1) over(partition by id_1 order by date_1 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) previous_balance,
    tab2.amount_pln1,
    tab1.amount - sum(tab2.amount_pln1) over(partition by id_1 order by date_1) balance
from
    tab1 inner join tab2 using(id_1)
```